# Use subdomain of referer for href link

Tags: javascript, href, referer

I have searched and tried a number of codes. I am trying to use my referer's subdomain (which is varied) as a clickable link. The link is an image and I can't tie-up how to get these together.

I have tried to utilise the

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="fetchlink">
document.referrer.replace("./", '').split('example.com')[0];
</script>
```

Which allows me to fetch the subdomain (although it always gives me a "." at the end of the the fetched subdomain and I can't do replace as my subdomain contains a variety of countries.

```
<a href="xxxxx"><img class="wp-image-268 size-full aligncenter" src="http://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/link.png" alt="" width="11%" height="5%" /></a>


<a id="fetchlink">Link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = document.getElementById('fetchlink'); 
a.href = document.referrer.replace("./", '').split('example.com')[0];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was using tags incorrectly:

```
<a id="fetchlink">Link<img class="wp-image-268 size-full aligncenter" src="http://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/link.png" alt="" width="11%" height="5%" /></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = document.getElementById('fetchlink'); 
a.href = document.referrer.replace("./", '').split("example.com")[0];
</script>
```